# Vim 8 packages interfering with indentation?

Tags: vim

I recently switched to Vim 8 to take advantage of the new [packages](https://vimhelp.org/repeat.txt.html#packages) feature. I noticed today that when I use the `=` key to autocorrect indentation it's now breaking everything .

Here's what the broken indentation looks like:

```
  1 class FriendPolicy < ApplictionPolicy
  2 class Scope
  3 attr_reader :user, :friend
  4 
  5              def initialize(user, friend)
  6   @user = user
  7   @friend = friend
  8   end
  9 
 10   def resolve; end
 11   end
 12 
 13   def index?; end
 14   end
```

Here's what the file should look like:

```
  1 class FriendPolicy < ApplictionPolicy
  2   class Scope
  3     attr_reader :user, :friend
  4 
  5     def initialize(user, friend)
  6       @user = user
  7       @friend = friend
  8     end
  9 
 10     def resolve; end
 11   end
 12 
 13   def index?; end
 14 end
```

**Things I've tried:**

1. I renamed the only package I have to something like `vim/pack/my_packages/start/vim-rubocop_asdfjlkdf` Then, my package is not loaded but the problem continued.
2. I renamed my `vim/pack` file to an arbitrary name like `vim/pack_asdlkfjasdf` Then the indentation started working again but of course my packages aren't loaded

Here's a link to my super simple vim file setup: https://github.com/latazzajones/dotfiles/tree/master/vim

Any advice would be helpful

Comment: I don't think that the 1. renaming prevented the rubocop plugin from being loaded, only the 2. one does this (Vim doesn't care how the package itself is named). So the problem clearly seems to be caused by the rubocop plugin.

Comment: Does adding `filetype indent on` to your `vimrc` help?

Comment: @Ralf Thanks! that was the trick!

Answer (score 0):

From looking at you `vimrc`, it seems the following is missing:

```
filetype plugin indent on
```

This enables to load filetype specific plugins and indent files.

See `:help :filetype`, `:help :filetype-plugin-on`and `:help :filetype-indent-on`.